# Is there a way to rename a field in a form in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using symfony2, I wondering if its possible to rename a field in a Form.

I mean... suppose i have an entity

```
class MyEntity{
    private $name 
    //more code
}
```

And i create a type for this entity:

```
class MyEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }
}
```

Is there a way to rename the field `name` in the form but the mapping to `name` attribute works. something like:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('MySuperName', null, array("mapping" => "name"))
            ;
    }
```

So the form param name becomes `entity[MySuperName]` instead of `entity[name]` but fills the `name` property on entity?

Comment: why do you need MySuperName? Just for display? you can use the `label` attribute for that.

Comment: Nop... i am reprogramming an API, but i don't want to change clients and i want to name things as i like. In this case `MySuperName` is what the client sends... and `name` is the name i want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`property_path`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path):

```
$builder
    ->add('MySuperName', null, array('property_path' => 'name'))
```

Another option would be to add get/set aliases to your `name` field:

```
public function getMySuperName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setMySuperName($mySuperName)
{
    $this->name = $mySuperName;

    return $this;
}
```